# How to create python game board

Tags: python, dataframe, format, nested-lists

I need help with creating something like this. (I´m just a beginner and I need some inspiration on how to create this board with these numbers, this board should parameter n, with this parameter i can choose how big will be this board [9x9 or 13x13]) Thx for every idea!

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
0       * * *
1       * D *
2       * D *
3 * * * * D * * * *
4 * D D D X D D D *
5 * * * * D * * * *
6       * D *
7       * D *   
8       * * *
```

My Board list looks like this:

```
board = [[' ',' ',' ','*','*','*',' ',' ',' '],
              [' ',' ',' ','*','D','*',' ',' ',' '],
              [' ',' ',' ','*','D','*',' ',' ',' '],
              ['*','*','*','*','D','*','*','*','*'],
              ['*','D','D','D','X','D','D','D','*'],
              ['*','*','*','*','D','*','*','*','*'],
              [' ',' ',' ','*','D','*',' ',' ',' '],
              [' ',' ',' ','*','D','*',' ',' ',' '],
              [' ',' ',' ','*','*','*',' ',' ',' ']]
```

Comment: you want: `[[y for y in x if y != ','] for x in board]`

Answer (score 0):

These two lines would work:

```
print(' '+' '.join(map(str,range(9))))
print('\n'.join([' '.join([str(i)]+v) for i,v in enumerate(board)]))
```

Output:

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
0       * * *      
1       * D *      
2       * D *      
3 * * * * D * * * *
4 * D D D X D D D *
5 * * * * D * * * *
6       * D *      
7       * D *      
8       * * *
```

Bunch of `str.join`s can do it!!!

Comment: Yeah it's working, but I need to make this board "nxn", i can choose dimensions of this board.

Comment: @PeterDeeks What do you mean?

Comment: you know, if you have some input and you write some parameter ex.13...and this will be dimensions of this board, like 13x13...if i write 9 board will have 9x9 like on the picture